# Create dynamic drop down list using append in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Hi i have a problem here creating drop down list in javascript by using of append()

```
$('#details_edit').append('<tr id ="123"><td>drop down here<td></tr>');
```

i have a variable  `$remarks_option` came from controller that have already a values

question is how to do it in javascript? please help. BTW im using CI here

thanks

Comment: What is your **$remarks_optio** value?

Comment: for example the value is like this                                      <select>
  <option value="testcode">test</option>
</select>

Comment: The function `append()` is not belonged to javascript. It is a jquery function. You need solution with jquery or pure javascript ?

Comment: javascript or jquery will do

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your dropdownlist is an html `select` object with `option` objects in it (which it should be), you can use the following code:

```
$('#details_edit').append($("<option/>", {
    value: '<?php echo $remarks_option; ?>',
    text: '<?php echo $remarks_option; ?>'
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
$('#details_edit').append('<tr id ="123"><td><?php echo $remarks_option; ?><td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works:

```
$('#details_edit').append($("<option></option>").attr("value","key Value").text("Your Value"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the response from AJAX , then this is a way to do things. Assume response is the parameter in your success callback.

```
var JSONtext = response;
var JSONobject = JSON.parse(JSONtext);

$('#details_edit').append('<tr id ="123"><td><select id="mySelect"></select><td></tr>');

$('#mySelect').append(new Option(JSONobject.name,JSONobject.value));
```

Oh well , my bad , I didn't see the OP's comment in which he says that he is getting the select box itself rather than an object. Keeping this answer here in case someone finds it useful!

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting value like " test  " from controller, then use following :

```
$('#details_edit').append('<tr id ="123"><td><?php print_r($remarks_optio);?><td></tr>');
```

And if you are getting option values only, then use like this :

```
var myOptions = {
    val1 : 'text1',
    val2 : 'text2'
};  // assume myoptions contains value returned by controller
var mySelect = $('#mySelect');
$.each(myOptions, function(val, text) {
    mySelect.append(
        $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
    );
});
```

Hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

The very basic of javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var opt_1 = document.createElement("option");
        opt_1.setAttribute('value', "0");
        opt_1.innerHTML = "-- Select --";
        var opt_2 = document.createElement("option");
        opt_2.setAttribute('value', "2");
        opt_2.innerHTML = "Option A";
        var opt_3 = document.createElement("option");
        opt_3.setAttribute('value', "3");
        opt_3.innerHTML = "Option B";

        var ddl = document.createElement("select");
        ddl.setAttribute('id', 'selectDynamic');
        ddl.addEventListener("change", function () {
            alert(this.value);
        }, false);

        ddl.appendChild(opt_1);
        ddl.appendChild(opt_2);
        ddl.appendChild(opt_3);

        document.getElementById('details_edit').parentNode.appendChild(ddl);
    });
```